# Kernel Error problem in Jupyter Notebook on PyCharm 2018 IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

I am struggling with **running Jupyter Notebook on PyCharm2018 Community Edition** in Windows 10. I created a `Virtual Environment` with python version 3.6.6 and other necessary packages. I installed `jupyter notebook` (ipython-7.8.0v, jupyter-1.0.0v) as well following its documentation. As, I am using a specific python version for this application, I want to create a separate `ipython kernel` (version 5.1.2) for python 3 in a specific path and then add it to jupyter kernelspecs as follows:

```
ipython kernel install --prefix /tmp

jupyter kernelspec install /tmp/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

When I run an example ipython notebook after following these instructions, the `notebook` is returning **Kernel Error** problem stating ***Could not find a kernel matching Python 2*** . I am unable to understand, why its resulting in this. There is no trace of python2 being used anywhere during my installation. I even created python3 kernels separately using above instructions and changed my notebook to kernel to that, but still the same **Kernel Error**. `Virtual Environment` I created for this application also uses python3.6 exec file from my Anaconda Installation.

I have looked around similar questions on this problem, but none of them could help me solve this so far. The back trace of this error is as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\***\pycharm_workspace\trail\venv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "D:\***\pycharm_workspace\trail\venv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<D:\***\pycharm_workspace\trail\venv\lib\site-packages\decorator.py:decorator-gen-125>", line 2, in initialize
  File "D:\***\pycharm_workspace\trail\venv\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\***\pycharm_workspace\trail\venv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 472, in initialize
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "D:\***\pycharm_workspace\trail\venv\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 199, in write_connection_file
    iopub_port=self.iopub_port, control_port=self.control_port)
  File "D:\***\pycharm_workspace\trail\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 141, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "D:\Anaconda3\envs\python36\lib\contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "D:\**\pycharm_workspace\trail\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 404, in secure_write
    win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
  File "D:\**\pycharm_workspace\trail\venv\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 359, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
    import win32api
**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.**
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to not update IDE to the latest stable version (2019.2.3)? I recall multiple DLL-related issues on Anaconda fixed along the way.

Comment: No specific reason actually. Using 2018 from long time and thought, this problem could be solved without updating software. However, looking at problem not being solved from last 3-4 days, now I am considering to update it.